# Filtrar dados em coluna de um relacionamento usando Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

**OBJETIVO: Em uma listagem de entidades Eloquent, quero filtrar pela coluna 'nome' que pertence à tabela relacionada 'pessoas'.**

Tenho um conjunto de dados sendo apresentado a uma view com DataTable. Esses dados estão vindo de duas tabelas relacionadas: **campanhas** e **pessoas**. No final tenho a seguinte composição:

```
dt_adesao  | valor | codigo | nome
2023-01-30 | 30.00 | A-365  | Mateus Silva
```

Colunas da tabela '**campanhas**':

```
'dt_adesao', 'dt_encerramento', 'valor', 'pessoa_id', 'grupo_id'...
```

Colunas da tabela '**pessoas**':

```
'nome', 'codigo', 'celular', 'dt_nasc'...
```

Relacionamento no **Model Campanha**

```
public function toPessoa(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pessoa::class, 'pessoa_id')->withDefault(['nome' => 'N/D']);
}
```

Eu preciso de ajuda para montar a query usando o Eloquent do Laravel, de tal forma que tenha ainda disponível os atributos, propriedades e relacionamentos dos Models. Eu até consegui fazer funcionar com Query Builder, mas assim ela não vem com todos os objetos montados, as propriedades personalizadas, então não é interessante.

O que preciso é retornar a lista, filtrando pelo nome que está no model 'Pessoa'.

---

**Em partes, consegui com query builder:**

```
$value = 'tiago';
$campanhas = DB::table('campanha')
    ->leftJoin('pessoas', 'pessoas.id', '=', 'campanha.pessoa_id')
    ->select('pessoas.nome', 'pessoas.codigo', 'campanha.*');

$campanhas->where('pessoas.nome', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
```

O que resulta na seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT campanha_pessoa.dt_adesao, campanha_pessoa.valor, pessoas.nome, pessoas.codigo
FROM campanha_pessoa
left Join pessoas ON campanha_pessoa.pessoa_id = pessoas.id
WHERE pessoas.nome LIKE '%tiago%'
```

Porém dessa forma perco as propriedades e atributos do Model.

Estou tentando com **sub-select**, até consigo montar a consulta, porém na hora de filtra dá erro.

```
$campanhas = CampPessoaPivot::with(['toPessoa','toGrupo','toSituacao'])
->addSelect([
    // nome: alias da sub-select
    'nome' => Pessoa::query()
        // You can use eloquent methods here
        ->select('nome')
        ->whereColumn('id', 'pessoa_id')
        ->latest()
        ->take(1),
    // codigo: alias da sub-select
    'codigo' => Pessoa::query()
        // You can use eloquent methods here
        ->select('codigo')
        ->whereColumn('id', 'pessoa_id')
        ->latest()
        ->take(1)
]);
```

Passei filtro assim:

```
$campanhas->where('(select nome from pessoas)', 'like', '"%tiago%"');
```

O seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(select nome from pessoas)' in 'where clause'

    SQL: select `campanha_pessoa`.*, 
(select `nome` from `pessoas` where `id` = `pessoa_id` and `pessoas`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 1) as `nome`, 
(select `codigo` from `pessoas` where `id` = `pessoa_id` and `pessoas`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 1) as `codigo` 
from `campanha_pessoa` where `(select nome from pessoas)` like "%tiago%" and `campanha_pessoa`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
        // Valor sendo consultado
        $value = 'thiago';

        // Inicia a consulta trazendo o relacionamento com pessoa
        $consulta = Campanha::with(['toPessoa']);

        // Quando houver pesquisa, filtra pelo nome da pessoa
        $consulta->when(
            $value,
            function ($query) use ($value){
                return $query->whereRelation('toPessoa', 'nome', 'ilike', '%'.$value.'%');
            }
        );

        // Resultados
        $campanhas = $consulta->get();
```

Não sei se entendi exatamente, mas tente dessa forma. Documentação sobre o método whereRelation() [aqui](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_whereRelation)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).